# How to calculate the average time complexity of the nearest neighbor search using kd-tree?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, kdtree

We know the complexity of the nearest neighbor search of kd-tree is O(logn). But how to calculate it? The main problem is the average time complexity of the back tracing. I have tried to read the paper "An Algorithm for Finding Best Matches in Logarithmic Expected Time", but it is too complicate for me. Does anyone know a simple way to calculate that?

Comment: This question would probably be better suited on [cs.se].

Comment: If you are a real programmer rather than a hack, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation in the paper is about as simple as possible for a rigorous analysis.

(NB This is the price of being a true computer scientist and software engineer. You must put the effort into learning the math. Knowing the math is what separates people who *think* they can write solid programs from those who actually can. Jon Bentley, the guy who invented kd-trees, did so when he was in high school. Take this as inspiration.)

If you want a rough intuitive idea that is *not* rigorous, here is one.

Assume we are working in 2d. The sizes of the geometric areas represented by the 2d-tree are the key.

In the average case, one point partitions the domain into 2 roughly equal-sized rectangles.  3 points into 4.  7 points into 8 parts.  Etc.  In general N points lead to N-1 roughly equal-sized rectangles.

It not hard to see that if the domain is 1x1, the length of a side of these parts is on average  O(sqrt(1/N)).

When you search for a nearest neighbor, you descend the tree to the rectangle containing the search point.  After doing this, you have used O(log N) effort to find a point within R = O(sqrt(1/N)) of the correct one.  This is just a point contained in the leaf that you discovered.

But this rectangle is not the only one that must be searched. You must still look at all others containing a point no more than distance R away from the search point, refining R each time you find a closer point.

Fortunately, the O(sqrt(1/N)) limit on R provides a tight bound on the average number of other rectangles this can be.  In the average case, it's about 8 because each equal-sized rectangle has no more than 8 neighbors.

So the total effort to search is O(8 log n) = O(log n).

Again, I repeat this is *not* a rigorous analysis, but it ought to give you a feel for why the algorithm is O(log N) in the average case.

Comment: Thank you very much not only for your answer to my question but also your advise to me. They are both what I want.Thank you:)

Comment: @Gene I have some difficulty to fully understand the original proof. Since you seem to know and understand the original proof, may I draw your attention to a [follow-up question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117081/time-complexity-for-nearest-neighbor-searches-in-kd-trees)? I created a new question on CS.SE since a comment seemed inappropriate.

Comment: @user1494080 Did you delete your question?